# How do I set up training using augmentation, but ensuring the actual images unaugmented were trained as well?

Tags: python, keras, data-augmentation

I am using data augmentation for a model and would like to include the original unaugmented images as well as the augmented images, in training.

I have used the following code so far:

```
main_dir = "____" (file directory)

train_dir = os.path.join(main_dir, 'training_set')
validation_dir = os.path.join(main_dir, 'validation_set')
test_dir = os.path.join(main_dir, 'test_set')

conv_base = VGG16(weights='imagenet',include_top=False,input_shape=(150, 150, 3))

conv_base.summary()

model = models.Sequential()
model.add(conv_base)
model.add(layers.Flatten())
model.add(layers.Dense(256, activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
model.summary()

conv_base.trainable = True
model.summary()

train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255,rotation_range=40,width_shift_range=0.2,height_shift_range=0.2,
  shear_range=0.2,zoom_range=0.2,horizontal_flip=True,fill_mode='nearest')

test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(train_dir,target_size=(150, 150),batch_size=20,class_mode='binary')
validation_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(validation_dir,target_size=(150, 150),batch_size=20,class_mode='binary')
test_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(test_dir,target_size=(150, 150),batch_size=20,class_mode='binary')

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',optimizer=optimizers.RMSprop(lr=2e-5),metrics=['acc'])

start = time.time()
history=model.fit_generator(train_generator,steps_per_epoch=300,epochs=15,validation_data=validation_generator,validation_steps=50,verbose=2)
print("Time taken to train the MLP %.1f seconds."%(time.time()-start))
```

Please let me know if anyone is able to help! Thanks :)

Comment: What have you tried already? Have you treid simply appending one to the other?

Answer (score 0):

So, `ImageDataGenerator` is not creating a batch of images that you can simply add images to. It is creating randomly transformed images *on each epoch*. while this may hurt your performance on the training data, it should improve performance on the validation and test data. Speaking of which, you shouldn'T run the image generator on your validation and test data because it will randomly change them every time and give your model a moving target.

This [tutorial](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2019/07/08/keras-imagedatagenerator-and-data-augmentation/) goes over the subject pretty well and should be helpful